# React Native - Modal in Custom Component not showing

Tags: react-native, react-native-modal

I am new to React Native and currently learning on developing a chat app.

I have a `Modal` that contain Rating UI

**Working with these approach**

ChatScreen.js

```
<Modal isVisible={showRateModal}  >
    <RatingModal />
</Modal>
```

RatingModal.js

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <RatingEmojiSection />
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Button/>
               
     </View>
</View>
```

---

**Not Working**

```
It works all fine but when I move `Modal` into `RatingModal.js`, the Modal wont be showing anymore. Here is my approach 
import { Modal } from 'react-native-paper';

<Modal isVisible={showRateModal}  >
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <RatingEmojiSection />
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                <Button/>
               
         </View>
    </View>
</Modal>
```

Anyone have idea why this could happen? PS: the `showRateModal` state is working fine. I just curious why can't I move the `Modal` wrapper into `RatingModal.js`?

Comment: Can you please update the code with imports and also if you are getting any errors ,please update the question with them :)

Comment: Are you trying to put Modal in another Modal? If so, it won't work, since you can't open one Modal inside another.

Comment: Nono, I had updated my question with imports. And also, originally I used `Modal` in ChatScreen.js, I want to move `Modal` into RatingModal.js but the modal cannot show.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two problems with your current code

First you are rendering two `Modal`s: ChatScreen.js contains a `<Modal>`, and then you `RatingModal` code also contains a `<Modal>` rendering.

Second: from the [react-native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal#visible) you can see that the required property is not `isVisible` but `visible`.

Fixing these two issues should fix your problem.

Comment: Hi, I had updated my question, the bottom is actually my trial and it is not working. The top 2 snippets are the working one. And also I am using `react-native-paper` so the `Modal` props is `isVisible`